# How to prevent auto convert time zone with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I deployed the database on AWS, where data about date-time is GMT+0. My time zone is GMT+7. And when I query data, the data about time zone is auto-convert to GMT+7. How can I prevent this action?

Comment: If you don't want time zone support, don't use `timestamp with time zone` but  `timestamp WITHOUT time zone`

Comment: I would advise against that. With ```timestamptz``` you know the timestamp is stored as UTC and therefore is anchored.  A ```timestamp``` is not anchored and unless you keep some external information about it's origin it is very easy to get thoroughly confused about its meaning.

Comment: To make this clearer, please add an example table schema showing the timestamp fields. Also indicate what you want the timestamps to show up as to the end user and why?

Answer (score 3):

Issuing `SET SESSION TIME ZONE 'UTC';` in your session will prevent the automatic conversion.

Comment: impossible. I really can't set session time zone to all customers around the world

Comment: @Riya How do your customers access the database?  Do they connect directly, or does the access go through an application tier?

Comment: they access through an application, which will show them data about date-time

Comment: @Riya Who writes the application?  Is it a middle-tier application or a client application?

Comment: We have a team to build this application. And I'm not really understanding about AWS or database. Just handling this issue

Comment: @Riya The timezone conversion is a display issue.  The timestamps are all stored and handled internally as UTC and then converted to the local timezone for display.  Your application developers should be dealing with this as a localization problem in their application.

Comment: Thanks for this it was driving me mental in pgAdmin even though I could see the data was fine!